# Excel update calculations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, finance

Is there is a way (formula) to update calculations automatically in a main sheet if you add a new sheet to the model or remove a sheet?

Comment: That would require VBA

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Do you know by any chance the VBA code to write such an undertaking?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, you can do multiple sheets like so `SUM(Sheet2:Sheet4!A1)`  Adding a sheet between 2 & 4 includes in the calc.

Comment: What about using ThisWorkbook module via `Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)` ? @FritzPressler

Comment: Thank you. It would be needed for the main sheet, which bundles the outcomes of the different data in the other sheets. The other sheets are always built the same.  The purpose is that if you add or delete one of the additional sheets that it automatically updates in the main sheet.

Comment: @FritzPressler You'll have to describe more precisely the concept of your sheet calculations - e.g. (sum) formulae only in the main sheet? do you execute a procedure to refresh the main sheet? ... - Note that the question may be closed because it unclear or needs more details.  *See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*.